# Optimization Algorithm for large search space

Tags: algorithm, optimization, heuristics

Problem:
Find a combination of 48 numbers (x) ranging from 1-6 that maximises an equation (y). The equation comprises of 48 distinct functions that are unknown and only take in one number per function.

```
max:     y = f1(x1) + f2(x2) + ... + f48(x48)
where:   x = {1:6}
example: x = [6, 1, 4, ..., 4] => y = 167
```

My first idea was to solve this using brute force, however, the search space is very large 6^48. Does anyone know of an algorithm that I could use or clever programming tricks?

Answer (score 1):

The search space if not that large at all.
y is the sum of 48 distinct functions, so you need to maximize each one of them. There are 6 possibilities for each f_i, in total you need to check 6*48=288 cases to brute force.

Start with some base answer like x = [1, ..., 1]. Find the optimal value for x_1, then x_2, etc.